# JMeter - Extracting and processing JSON response

Tags: jmeter

I have a JSON response with hotel results with providers and the offers from the providers.
Something like below.I am running the thread for 15 hotels and retriving provider and offer data from all the hotels. 
Now I want to find out how many offers each provider has for all the 15 hotels. 
For example, provider BBB.com with provider index 1 has 2 offers for HotelABC.This provider will have multiple offers for other hotels as well. Is there a way to do this?

```
{
    "name":HotelABC, 

    "providers":
    [
        { [0]
            "name":"AAA.com",
        },
        {  [1]
            "name":"BBB.com",
        },
        {  [2]
            "name":"skoosh.com",  
        }
    ]
    "results":
    [
        {
            "providerIndex":0,
        },
        {
            "providerIndex":1,
        },
        {
            "providerIndex":2,
        },
        {
            "providerIndex":1,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you give details on your workflow? I.e. you say "I want to find out " - what do you mean by that? Since it's JMeter, I assume you want to save this information in some form, and use it elsewhere. So where? Is it assertion? Or is the loop based on number of requests? etc.

Comment: I am basically doing a hotel search and want to make sure that we are getting all the data from all the suppliers. I am totally new to jmeter so I am not sure how it works. Is it possible to display the data in a table format in a listener or just display the data somewhere or write it on a file?

Comment: JMeter is a performance/load testing tool. Manual inspection of the data is quite unusual usage of it, and it doesn't have fancy ways to parse or display the data. If displaying / manual inspection is important maybe you should use other tools like Postman, SoapUI or even create a simple web page, where you can issue that call and format its response as you want.